# How to safely evaluate code while allowing access to the DOM and library functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, security, dom, eval

I'm currently trying to implement the evaluation of user scripts on a website. I want these scripts to have access to the DOM and some library functions. I've been able to run scripts securely, but they can't access the DOM because they are in a new context. How can I safely evaluate untrusted code in JavaScript while still allowing DOM access?

Comment: Is a user's script going to be evaluated in another user's browser too? Or only in their own browser? **Edit after your comment below:** ok, there's basically no added risk if a user's script can only run in their own browser, there is no need for any security _(they can already do anything from their developer tools)_. But if newbie users copy/paste code they don't understand from someone else, this can become a huge issue. That's what I wanted to know

Comment: Only in the user's browser - however, users can make copies of other's scripts for their own use.